# Basis of $H^4(\prod\mathbb CP^\infty;\mathbb Z)$

Tags: algebraic-topology, homology-cohomology

I would like to show the following is a basis of the free abelian group $H^4\left(\prod\mathbb CP^\infty;\mathbb Z\right)$.

Let $\omega_k$ be the dual to the copy of $S^2\approx\mathbb CP^1$ in the $k$-th copy of $\mathbb CP^\infty$. Then the claim is that $$H^4\left(\prod\mathbb CP^\infty;\mathbb Z\right)=\mathbb Z\{\omega_i\cup\omega_j\}_{i,j}.$$

(This is from a book. I assume "dual" means "Poincare dual" in this case.)

I tried using the Kunneth theorem, but my dimensions are wrong. In particular, I got that $H^4\left(\prod\mathbb CP^\infty\right)$ is isomorphic to the direct sum of terms of *either* the form $H^0\otimes\dots\otimes H^0\otimes H^2\otimes H^2$ or $H^0\otimes\dots\otimes H^0\otimes H^4$, where the $H^2$'s and $H^4$'s can be moved around. But if the claim in the book is true, then I shouldn't be getting any $H^0\otimes\dots\otimes H^0\otimes H^4$ terms.

If I'm able to get rid of those terms, then I think the claim from the book should follow. Is that right?

I'd appreciate some explanation for where I went wrong (probably used the Kunneth theorem wrong...I thought it was the same for cohomology as it is for homology though). It's possible my approach won't work, so any proof of the claim would also be great. There wasn't any explanation in the book itself, so I feel like I'm missing something simple.

Comment: Not really sure what the appropriate thing to do here is, but I realized my problem. Basically, I was assuming that $i\ne j$, but obviously there's no such requirement. So the $H^4$ terms correspond to cases when $i=j$. Kind of a silly mistake...

Comment: I think "dual" here means "algebraic dual" instead of "Poincare dual".